# How does Windows 10 calculate app's battery drain?

Tags: windows-10, battery-life

I just got Windows 10, and its "Battery Usage" screen in settings has me confused.

I've had Eclipse (the IDE) open pretty much every second since I upgraded to Windows 10, but you wouldn't be able to tell that by the usage screen:

[image: Windows 10 Battery Usage Screenshot]

Then there's weird things like the Photos, Maps and Calendar apps taking up some (negligible) battery, even though I'm fairly certain I've never even opened any of them yet.

It's not even like its only native applications show up here, since Chrome has characteristically taken its place at the top of the list.

What's going on here?

I'm on a Surface Pro 2 if that means anything.

Comment: Chrome is a native application. ;) It’s probably something like `((program CPU time) / (total CPU time)) * battery drain`.

Comment: Ok, I doubt Webroot is though, and it shows up.

Comment: Of course it’s native, what else would it be? You can’t properly interface with the necessary security interfaces when using Java or whatnot.

Comment: @DanielB I think I'm misusing the term "native". I meant applications that come with with OS.

Comment: Photos, Maps and Calendar are Metro app, either the live tile or lock screen notification permission (even if you don't set it for lock screen) will take some CPU time.

Meanwhile Windows never really see Eclipse running, it only know JRE is called and running something. Not sure why Microsoft don't log JRE usage though, probably .NET, Flash and Air also exempted.

Comment: @Martheen But Eclipse is open constantly, how can it not know that it's running?

Comment: It doesn't see Eclipse. It sees JRE running something. And for some reason, probably since JRE is used by various app, Microsoft just elect to exempt JRE from the stat

Comment: Well that's not very useful -_-. Given how often its open, I'm sure it's eating battery power. They should have set it up like android did. I find Android's battery screen really useful.